# How can I remove the vertical line divider on the bottom nav bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

On smaller devices like iPhone 12, it works perfectly fine, but when I open it one bigger devices like iPhone 12 Pro, Pro Max and iPad, the bottom nav bar shows a vertical line divider. How can I remove such?

I'm using a customized [convex app bar package](https://bar.hacktons.cn/)

```
 ConvexAppBar( 
      controller: _tabController,
      curveSize: 0,
      curve: Curves.ease,
      style: TabStyle.fixedCircle,
      color: Colors.white,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      activebgcolor: Colors.red,
      activeColor: Colors.red,
      items:...)
```

Comparison of the devices (icons liquefied for security)
[image: comparison of the devices (icons liquefied for security)]

Comment: Have you already investigated the widget if there are any borders defined? If so, just set their color to `transparent` or completely remove them.

Comment: try this: https://pub.dev/packages/home_indicator

Answer (score 2):

This is actually provided by iPhone OS ,, Its not a issue of flutter...